# Camel SSH keyPairProvider option

Tags: apache-camel, key-pair

Can anyone suggest how to specify the keyPairProvider option with Camel SSH component?

I am trying to connect to a remote SSH server using Camel SSH component and KeyPairProvider option. The documentation is not clear on how to use this option, the syntax or the value we need to provide etc. I have tried giving the classname, full classpath, key file name etc. Nothing works. I always get the below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a suitable setter for property: keyPairProvider as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.sshd.common.KeyPairProvider with value file:com.example.tree.custom.CustomFileKeyPairProvider
    at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperty(IntrospectionSupport.java:555)
    at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperty(IntrospectionSupport.java:565)
    at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperties(IntrospectionSupport.java:453)
    at org.apache.camel.util.EndpointHelper.setProperties(EndpointHelper.java:249)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.setProperties(DefaultComponent.java:264)
    at org.apache.camel.component.ssh.SshComponent.createEndpoint(SshComponent.java:47)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:508)
    ... 18 more
```

This is my route

```
from("direct:sshroute")
.to("ssh://sshuser1@10.115.136.176?keyPairProvider=com.example.tree.custom.CustomFileKeyPairProvider")
```

If I do not give keyPairProvider and change the route to use password, it works fine.

I also want to mention that if I create my own SSHComponent, set the CustomFileKeyPairProvider and add it to CamelContext (as given in the tests package), it is works fine too. 
But just want to know if we use default Camel Component, how do we use this option.

Thanks 
- Ravi

Comment: Were you able to find some information regarding this?

Comment: are you trying to use use SSH PublicKeys to log on to a remote SSH without providing a password?  Just want to double check because I'm actively working on that.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to come up with the answer to this because I also need to be able to deliver files via the Camel SFTP route.  Luckily, I have found what works.

Basically, what you need to do is present the Private key, not the Public key, to your Camel route.  The assumption here is that you generated a public key to share with the remote SSH/SFTP server, delivered that public key to the remote site and, either you or the remote administrator, placed that file in the "authorized_keys" container on the remote site.

That being said, you construct your Camel SFTP route as such:

```
<to uri="sftp://username@remote_server_address/directoryname?privateKeyFile=/full/path/to/your/private_key/id_dsa&amp;knownHostsFile=/full/path/to/your/known_hosts" />
```

With this address, I was able to send my file to my remote destination without logging on:

```
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> Connecting to 10.0.0.110 port 22
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> Connection established
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.4
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.44
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> Host '10.0.0.110' is known and mathces the RSA host key
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> Next authentication method: publickey
11/27 23:35:03 INFO  [aCamelQueue]] SftpOperations                 - JSCH -> Authentication succeeded (publickey)
```

I go into a bit more detail in my findings over on [my website](http://www.twobitcoder.com/?p=427) but this is the main jist.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi Mastashake57, thanks for your reply. I am looking for SSH connection using key pair. For SFTPComponent, I am already using the above mentioned way. The problem with the SSHComponent is that the camel documentation does not give example on how to use keyPairProvider option for inbuilt Camel SSH Component.

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for SSH connection using key pair, you can do it with the `certResource` option, like

```
from("direct:sshroute")
.to("ssh://sshuser1@10.115.136.176?certResource=file:path/to/your/private_key)
```

it's said in the doc that you can prefix path with `classpath:`, `file:`, or `http:`, but I've only tried `file:`.